# sheaf cohomology of a single point

Tags: homology-cohomology, sheaf-theory

Is it true that $H^q$({$\star$}, $\mathscr{A}$)= $H^q$({$\star$}, $\mathscr{B}$), q$\geq$ 0? Where $\mathscr{A}$ and $\mathscr{B}$ are two different sheaves on {$\star$}, the single point space.

Answer (score 3):

In general $$H^0(X,\mathscr{A})=\Gamma(\mathscr{A})$$ in the case of a one point space, $H^q(p,\mathscr{A})=0$ for $q\geq 1$.

Comment: Is there a reason for $H^q(p, \mathscr{A})$=0 for q$\geq$ 1? Thanks for explaining.

Comment: Sure there is only one point so $\Gamma(\mathscr{A})=\mathscr{A}_p$. to define coholomogy we take an exact resolution $0\to \mathscr{A} \to \mathscr{F}^0\to \cdots $ that is exact on the stalks, and apply the global sections functor $\Gamma$. In the case of one point $\Gamma$ just results in another exact sequence. Its like the identity.

Comment: so why is the global sections functor applied to those injective objects $\mathscr{F}^i$ preserving exactness?

Comment: Sheaf cohomology measures how much it doesnt preserve exactness, but in a space with one point, the global section and the stalk are the same. So basically nothing happens. Sheaf cohomology is about the difference between stalk exactness and section exactness.

Comment: so what is $\Gamma(\mathscr{F}^i)$?